# How to generate a list of friends and edges between mutual friends using FQL?

Tags: facebook-fql

I would like to visualize all the connections between mutual friends. In order to do it I have to create a list of my friends and then generate a list of edges.

For example if I have the following friends:

```
friend1
friend2
friend3
friend4
friend5
friend6
```

and friend1 has friends:

```
me
friend2
friend3
friend4
```

and friend2 has friends:

```
me
friend1
friend4
```

the following list of (undirected) edges should be created:

```
friend1, friend2
friend1, friend3
friend1, friend4
friend2, friend4
```

Does anyone know how to create a query to retrieve a list of edges between mutual friends the same way as it is indicated in the above example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're limited by the API to getting only the friends of a user, and **not** friends of friends of a user, it's going to be difficult for you to implement in a non-policy violating way.